# How to get the number of code lines written per quarter out of git repository

Tags: git, count, line

First things first, I am not a developer! However, I want to pull the following out of a git repository:
How many lines of code per e.g. quarter (in order to calculate bugs/kloc)
What I could achieve so far is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ6rN.png)

Now I know already the total number of code lines within this path.
I also know there is lots of Info out there - I just can´t adapt the given examples :-(

Thanks in Advace
Bernd

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, where the date in `--since` can go back one quarter or however far back you like. The following command gives the number of lines in `javascript` files (including comments) since 2013-01-30.

```
$ git log --format="" --since="2013-01-30" --name-only | grep ".*\.js$" | xargs wc -l
```

The output of that will be a list of files with the word count for each, that you might use for something, but the final line of output will be:

> 264488 total

You can also supply relative arguments to `--since`, e.g. `--since="{3 months ago}"` to be more in line with `quarter`.